# MySQL Dynamic Table issue

Tags: mysql, sql

Every month we get a CSV file that contains 300+ columns. The layout of the file can change whenever, and columns can be added/removed. I'm in need of a way to create a dynamic table that contains the exact number of columns needed. I don't care about column names, they can be Column1, Column2, etc.. and I plan to set all types to Varchar(500).

Ideally what I would I want to accomplish is a stored procedure that I can simply pass in the number of columns needed and it will loop to create the necessary Table Definition sql and then execute that sql.

Is accomplishing this even possible? I had started to write the following:

```
BEGIN
Declare loopvar int default 1;
Declare tsql VarChar(5000);
Declare table_definition VarChar(8000);
Declare tablename varchar(20);
Set table_definition = 'Column';
set tablename = 'npi_data';
Set loopvar = 1;
While loopVar < 362 DO
  set tsql = table_definition + loopvar + 'varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL' ;
  set loopvar = loopvar + 1;
end while;
 set tsql = 'CREATE TABLE' + tablename + '(' + tsql + ') ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8';
 execute tsql;
END;
```

I'd like something close to that but all I really need is the ability to create a table with any given number of columns.

Thanks!

Comment: Having your columns named Column1 and Column2 is realy bad practice. Why not use some `@tableColumns VARCHAR(8000)` parameter where each column names would be coma separated?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to be able to pass a list of column names, like `'A,B,C'`, and use it to generate a list of column definitions, like `A varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,B varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,C varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL` and, eventually, a CREATE TABLE statement with that definition list, you could use an approach like this:

```
...
SET columnnames = 'A,B,C';
SET sql = CONCAT(
  REPLACE(columnnames, ',', ' varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,'),
  ' varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL'
);
SET sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', tablename, ' (', sql, ')');
...
```

That is, every comma in the name list is expanded so as to complete the definition of the column preceding the comma. As the last item isn't followed by a comma, the type is simply concatenated one more time to the result of `REPLACE`.

Alternatively, to avoid the repetition of the `varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL` bit, you could do this:

```
...
SET columnnames = 'A,B,C';
SET sql = REPLACE(CONCAT(columnnames, ','), ',', ' varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,');
SET sql = LEFT(sql, LENGTH(sql) - 1);
SET sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', tablename, ' (', sql, ')');
...
```

In this case, a comma is added after the last name, *then* all commas in the resulting string are replaced like in the previous examples. As a final touch to the list, the trailing comma is removed and finally the complete statement is built.

Either way, no loop is needed.

Comment: The number of columns is the dynamic part, so I do need a loop to iterate through any possible number of columns creating a definition for each. I wont be able to pass the list of column names, and I don't have time to open the file and type out 300+ column names weekly.